# MobX observable component names hidden in stack trace

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react-lite

Here is a [component](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-browser-r83i0q?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js) that intentionally throws an error:

[image]

The `App` component is labelled as `observerComponent` in the stack track. However, if we remove the `observer` wrapper around our component (replace line 11 with line 12) the component name displays in the stack trace.

[image]

MobX obfuscating component names make it difficult to debug.

How can I retain the component name in the stack trace while keeping my component as a MobX observer?

Comment: Have you seen the [issue on github](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/3438)?

Comment: I hadn't found that, thank you for sharing. It looks like it was a bug in the older `mobx-react-lite` version I'm using. Feel free to post that answer and I will award you the bounty for being the first to find that issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it was a bug (or rather something that got broken during React 17->18 transition) and it was fixed some time ago ([maybe in this PR](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/pull/3590)), so you just need to update to the latest version of MobX and `mobx-react`.

See Codesandbox:

[image: Edit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76349390]

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This issue was created by some changes in how react handles `name` and `displayName` for components in stack traces.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/3438) on mobX's github page, and a work-around has already been implemented.

You just need to update your `mobx-react-lite` version.

Answer (score -2):

You can set the `displayName` property on the component to retain the component name in the stack trace:

```
const MyComponent = observer((props) => {
  ...
});

MyComponent.displayName = 'MyComponent';
```

Comment: I've read this solution on various threads but it doesn't work. See example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-orla-d50ybh?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I see the problem. You can wrap into observe a little bit later, like [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-hermann-s7ie5n?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This also doesn't work unfortunately, if you pull up the console in your linked example you can see the same issue is happening.